# Duplicate row after left join

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to write a query which as follow:

```
select distinct  bsg.id as bsgId,
s.system_id as sysId,
g.code_no as gameNo,
u.user_name as nameOfUser,
s.score_code as scoreId,
p.name as cityOfGame

from score s
join scoreGr sg on sg.id = s.scoreGr_id
join bigScoreGr bsg on sg.bigScoreGr_id = bsg.id
join game g on bsg.fld_case_id = g.id
join user u on s.user_id = u.id
join system_number sn on g.id = sn.game_id
join system_doc sd on sd.system_number_id = sn.id
left join parameter p on sd.city_id = p.id
```

Until I have joined with parameter table, result is as expected. The result seems like below:

```
bsgId| sysId | gameNo | nameOfUser | scoreId
--------------------------------------------------
1234 | abcde | G-12   | admin      | G-12/1/1
1235 | abcdf | G-15   | admin      | G-15/1/3
1234 | abcdf | G-12   | user1      | G-12/1/8
1237 | abcdf | G-16   | user1      | G-16/2/4
```

However, parameter table is something big and system_doc has some null values in its city_id column. When I add the left join part of my query, it becomes like that:

```
bsgId| sysId | gameNo | nameOfUser | scoreId  | city
--------------------------------------------------
1234 | abcde | G-12   | admin      | G-12/1/1 | city1
1235 | abcdf | G-15   | admin      | G-15/1/3 | city5
1235 | abcdf | G-15   | admin      | G-15/1/3 | 
1234 | abcdg | G-12   | user1      | G-12/1/8 | city4
1234 | abcdg | G-12   | user1      | G-12/1/8 | 
1237 | abcdf | G-16   | user1      | G-16/2/4 |
```

I do not want rows like 3rd and 5th ones. To avoid these rows which has null in their city columns and "*has the exact same data except city field*" (I mean city can be null actually,as in the last row, but having row #2 makes row #3 useless, so **I only want row #2**) I have used `distinct on(scoreId)`, but it did not worked since I have lost row #2 but not row #3.

How could I eliminate those duplicate rows which has null in their city fields? I hope my question is clear.

Comment: You want `distinct on (bsgId, sysId, gameNo, nameOfUser, scoreId)` as far as I can tell. Not just `distinct on(scoreId)`

Comment: actually they are same since scoreId is unique on all those field you have written. But even so, I got undesired result. Instead eliminating rows with null city, this query sometimes eliminates non-null ones

Answer (score 1):

It's a postgresql bug.

> left join parameter p on sd.city_id = p.id

Try this

```
left join parameter p on p.id = p.id
WHERE sd.city_id = p.id
```

(I have answered this so anyone looking for will now know about this bug)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a composite key. Try to mention all columns of composite key i.e. if you have `primary key(pk1, pk2)` then `select * from table1 left join table2 on table1.pk1=table2.pk1 and table2.pk2=table2.pk2`